# How can I update ehcache on multiple nodes?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, multiple-instances

I have app that is running on two machines, and I am using the ehcache. I see that whenever I update the cache, it only updates either of the machines ehcache but not both. How can I update both? Is that even possible?

I was using EJB to do the caching but I changed it because I didn't want to use EJB just because I needed cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Enterprise Ehcache or the free open source version? The enterprise version is capable of distributed updates, not the open source one (which is standalone).

Comment: how sure are you of this?

Comment: Pretty sure, I work for Terracotta as a Software Engineer :-) Standalone Ehcache can at best provide Weak Consistency for select use cases. Immutable data sets can be used without any problem, but for mutable data, you could use Time To Live policies. Let's say your consistency window is 2 seconds. In that case, you can set up Ehcache to have a Time To Live value of 2 seconds. Any element whose age > 2 seconds will be deleted from the cache in this case, and the app will have to go to the Database to reload. Read more here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-topologies

Comment: haha thanks. what i wanna do is basically have the app grab stuff from the cache whenever possible. the cache get cleared once there is a db change.

Comment: @Dhruv  is it the same case still ? or now open source is supporting distributed caching. ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to expose some sort of URL to update the cache directly on the nodes themselves instead of the URL that routes to each node.